# Need to take out For Loop Inside another For loop

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, visualforce, salesforce-lightning

In apex i trying to take out below for loop inside for loop .

Below Code base is iterating list if Sobject records.

```
 for(SObject sObj: listRecords){
      Map<String,Vals> RowsValsItemListMap = new Map<String,Vals>();
      List<Vals> ValsItemList = new List<Vals>();
      
      Map<String, Object> fieldsToValue = sObj.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();
      system.debug('Value for is: fieldsToValue' +fieldsToValue);
      
      map01.put(sObj, fieldsToValue);
      
      for (String fieldName : fieldsToValue.keySet()){
          system.debug('Value for fieldName is: ' +fieldName);                  
          Vals ValsItem = new Vals();                    
          ValsItem.val = fieldsToValue.get(fieldName);                
          //ValsItem.val = (String)fieldsToValue.get(fieldName);                        
          RowsValsItemListMap.put(fieldName.toLowerCase(), ValsItem);                
      }
```

}

Any help will be really appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

What is your code trying to achieve? What's the reason you need to eliminate loops, you have some performance issues?

At a glance it looks hard to optimise, you seem to be looping through all rows (sobjects) and all columns (populated fields), it's hard top optimise such thing when making a CSV output for example.

But looking closer I can see some stuff that looks like mistakes. We can optimise them away; the question is whether you really wanted to do these things.

1. `List<Vals> ValsItemList = new List<Vals>();` - this variable seems to not be used anywhere and besides - it's reset on every iteration anyway. Kill it?
2. Next thing:

   ```
   for(SObject sObj: listRecords){
       Map<String,Vals> RowsValsItemListMap = new Map<String,Vals>();
       // ... unimportant

       for (String fieldName : fieldsToValue.keySet()){
           // ... unimportant

           RowsValsItemListMap.put(fieldName.toLowerCase(), ValsItem);                
       }
   }
   ```

This `RowsValsItemListMap` is the outer loop's local variable. There's no point setting it, it'll be invisible outside of the loop anyway. Kill it. If it's needed in some code you didn't paste - look what you're doing. You reset the variable on every iteration. You might have just deleted the outer loop and used inner loop only on the last element (`listRecords]listRecords.size()-1]`), same result.

3. That leaves us with pretty much only `map01.put(sObj, fieldsToValue);`. We don't know what it does and it's probably a mistake to index maps by sObject - if you change a field in the sObject the map's inner hash key will change and you might not be able to find your element anymore. If it's really needed - well, you need only outer loop for this, here's your optimisation.